# How do I negotiate having a NextJS fronted and Flask backend with Social Logins?

Tags: authentication, flask, next.js

So I'm attempting my first NextJS/Flask app for a personal project i'm working on.

Flask has the ability to do JWT and manage it so does NextJS.....

I see that Flask has social login ability so does NextJS... I only need one...so I have the following questions...

so before I fumble around a bit...

1. Do I need both. should I just use Flask or NextJS but not cross pollinate.
2. If I am to cross pollinate. Which one for the social login and cookie managment? Flask+JWT or NextJS.as in maintaining the login once approved.

thanks